# Псевдоэлемент :after content url('puth/img.png) как изменить размер картинки?

Tags: html, sass

```css
.title_card::after {
    content: url(/images/src/Akcent.png);
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_card">
    <span>Сайт визитка</span>
</div>
```

Необходимо задать размер картинки в content, правила width не дает результат. Кто знает ответ? Подскажите правильный вариант. Там просто картинка с полосой для подчеркивания заголовка, и при изменении размера картинка остается неизменной, надо задать медиа запрос с уменьшенным размером картинки.

Answer (score -1):

```
 transform: scale(.7)
```

Правильный ответ!!!

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/882052)

Comment: Почему не является, это же  работает?